# The property 'visualTree' is set more than once in windows Phone 8 c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

In my windows phone application, I want to get all contacts with checkbox and show in list box

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <StackPanel Height="Auto" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,10">
            <TextBlock x:Name="ContactResultsLabel" Text="results are loading..." Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
            <ListBox x:Name="ContactResultsData" ItemsSource="{Binding listOfContacts}" Height="293" Margin="24,0,0,0">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox Name="contactChk" IsChecked="true" Foreground="Black" Background="Black" BorderBrush="Black"></CheckBox>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="ContactResultsName" Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="50"></TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

But when I add `Checkbox` and `Textblock` in the `DataTemplate` of the listbox it gets me error below:

`The property 'visualTree' is set more than once`

I don't understand why it gives, Kindly suggest me, waiting for your reply.
Thanks.

Comment: You would have to put them inside an element that supports multiple children, like a stackpanel or a grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add only one Element root in DataTemplate, code can change like this:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
        <CheckBox Name="contactChk" IsChecked="true" Foreground="Black" Background="Black" BorderBrush="Black"></CheckBox>
        <TextBlock x:Name="ContactResultsName" Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="50"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

`DataTemplate` can only have **One** child. you used `CheckBox` and `TextBlock`.Put them in single `Grid/StackPanel`.Hope this Helps.